# Using WCF basicHttpBinding standard configuration

Tags: authentication, wcf

Hello I have a WCF service which is installed on my laptos's IIS.
Its a very basic service . I configured the endpoint like this :

```
<service name="Library.Service1">
        <endpoint address="HttpAuthNoneSecNone" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="Library.IService1" name="HttpAuthNoneSecNone"></endpoint>
.....
</service>
```

As far as I know basicHttpBinding should have a default configuration of Serucity = "None" and clientCredentialType = "None".

I am calling the service via a client like this :

```
svc = new HttpAuthBasicSecTransport.Service1Client("HttpAuthNoneSecNone");
string r = svc.GetData(1);
```

The call to svc.GetData() always fails with the following exception :

```
"HTTP request not allowed  with 'Anonymous'  authentication client scheme."
```

I wonder where is the problem since I have tried both enabling and disabling anonymous authentication on mi IIS.

Moreover, since I have no authentication scheme (and no security) configured, shouldn't it work fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a mismatch between the site's configuration, which was configured to require SSL certificate,and the binding configuration, which doesn't require security by default .
Once I disabled SSL certificate request on the site, the call succeeded .
I still have to keep Basic authentication enabled if I want the client to be updated automatically by the ide's feature, since mexHttpBinding seems to require Basic authentication by default.